# Should bootstrap/compiled.php be version controlled?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My understanding is that `bootstrap/compiled.php` is auto-generated by running `php artisan optimize`, and is only intended for performance gains on production servers. Therefore it shouldn't committed in version control.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - it should not be included in version control.

Laravel excludes this file by default in the `.gitignore` file included in the framework root:

**.gitignore**

```
/bootstrap/compiled.php
...
```

Comment: thanks. My .gitignore was out of date because I've upgraded from an older version of Laravel.